# Detail of a trick evaluating HQET Self Energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

I have already asked this question in math SE with no luck. I'm reading the HQET book, and I see this in the book Heavy Quark Physics([the book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=codDQK5OQDIC&pg=PR4&lpg=PR4&dq=heavy+quark+physics+aneesh+manohar+Wise&source=bl&ots=hhUdK-xUjN&sig=3ps5Hk1ZnT1Vz-jhvmpqeQ2I-bE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJx6n23I3LAhXIk5QKHR3gBnUQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=heavy%20quark%20physics%20aneesh%20manohar%20Wise&f=false), it is on Page.79).

The original integration is

$$-\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)g^2\mu^{\epsilon}\int \frac{d^nq}{(2\pi)^n}\frac{1}{(q^2-m^2)v\cdot (q+p)}$$

After some calculations, it becomes

$$-\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)g^2 \mu^{\epsilon}\int _0^{\infty}d\lambda \frac{i}{(4\pi)^{2-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\Gamma (\frac{\epsilon}{2})\left(\lambda ^2 - 2\lambda v\cdot p + m^2\right)^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$$

In the book, it says, define

$$I(a,b,c)\equiv \int _0^{\infty} d\lambda \left(\lambda ^2 +2 b\lambda +c\right)^a=\frac{1}{1+2a}\left(\left(\lambda ^2 +2b\lambda +c\right)^a\left(\lambda +b\right)\left.\right|_{0}^{\infty}+2a(c-b^2)I(a-1,b,c)\right)$$

And

$$\int _0^{\infty}d\lambda \left(\lambda ^2 + 2\lambda b + c\right)^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}=\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\left(\color{blue}{c^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}b}-\epsilon (c-b^2)\int _0^{\infty}d\lambda \left(\lambda ^2 + 2\lambda b + c\right)^{-1}\right)$$

**I'm stucked by the first term, it says in dimensional regulation, as long as $z$ depends on $\epsilon$ in a way that allow one to analytically continue $z$ to negative values**

$$\lim _{\substack{\lambda \to \infty}}\lambda ^z = 0$$
I really don't understand what does this mean.

In fact, I know some other method to evaluate the original integration, I just want to understand and learn the trick to evaluate $\int _0^{\infty}d\lambda \left(\lambda ^2 + 2b\lambda  + c\right)^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ here.

I need help. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What is $z$, what does it have to do with the term you highlighted, and what is the question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think can consider $z$ as some constant. From the integral by part recursion relation, I think the term I highlighted from $$\frac{1}{1+2a}\left(\lambda ^2+2b \lambda +c\right)^a\left(\lambda +b\right)\left.\right|_0^{\infty}$$ If $$\lim _{\lambda \to \infty}\lambda ^z=0$$ holds for any constant $z$ in DR, immediately I can see $$\frac{1}{1+2a}\left(\lambda ^2+2b \lambda +c\right)^a\left(\lambda +b\right)\left.\right|_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}c^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}b$$ But I don't understand why $\lim _{\lambda \to \infty}\lambda ^z=0$

Comment: Uhhh...$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\lambda^z = 0$ clearly only holds for $z<0$, is $1$ for $z=0$, and diverges for $z>0$. That's pure and elementary math, I don't get what this has to do with dimensional regularization.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's exactly where I'm stacked, according to book, you can find it as (3.12) on page.79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $a=-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ into your first expression for $I(a,b,c)$. The integral equals to 
$$\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}(\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\frac{\lambda +b}{((\lambda+b)^2+c-b^2)^{\epsilon/2 }}-c^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}b-\epsilon(c-b^2)\int_0^{\infty}d\lambda \frac{1}{(\lambda^2+2b\lambda+c)^{1+\epsilon/2}})$$

Dimensional regularization means that we first compute the integral  with some $\epsilon$ such that the integral converges. Then we take the limit $\epsilon\to 0$, with the poles properly subtracted by counter terms, to get a finite result. From your integral or from the above expression it is clear that when $\epsilon>1$ the integral converges. Therefore set $\epsilon>1$ first so that the term involving $\lambda\to\infty$ will vanish, and then let $\epsilon\to 0$. Based on what you wrote, I believe there is a sign error on the term $c^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}b$ in your expression.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for answering! Yes, there is a sign error in the question. I still feel surprised that $\epsilon$ is allowed to be as large as $\epsilon > 1$, however, I can't find a reason that why not allowed to set $\epsilon > 0$ to regulate then use $\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}$. This is very useful, thank you very much!